# Class<? extends class> isn't working

Tags: java, list, class, inheritance

I have a class that takes a argument of List< Class< ? extends MiniGameArena>>, but when I add a class to this list, it is throwing an error saying that I need to change List< Class< ? extends MiniGameArena>>, to the exact class I am using as the argument.

```
new MinigameSetupManager(this, Collections.singletonList(TestArena.class), arenaManager); //TestArena.class is the error here

public MinigameSetupManager(Main plugin, List<Class<? extends MiniGameArena>> arenaTypesSupported, MiniGameArenaManager<?> arenaManager) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.manager = arenaManager;
    this.arenaTypesSupported = ImmutableList.copyOf(arenaTypesSupported);
    plugin.registeredListener(this);
    plugin.registerCommand(new commands());
}
```

This is the exact error "The constructor MinigameSetupManager(Main, List< Class< TestArena>>, MiniGameArenaManager< TestArena>) is undefined"

Comment: A `List<Class<TestArena>>` is not a subtype of `List<Class<? extends MiniGameArena>>`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

Comment: How would I fix that?